# pg_query_params return error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

```
$Query = pg_query_params($db, 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = $1 AND password=(crypt(\'$2\',password)) LIMIT 1', array(33,'thepassword'));
```

"bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1"

The problem seem around the '$2' parameter, heredoc string doesnt works.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Single quotes are used in SQL for string literals. That means that this:

```
'$2'
```

is just a string that contains the characters `$` and `2` rather than a placeholder. If you want a placeholder, you need to leave out the quotes:

```
$Query = pg_query_params($db, '...password=(crypt($2,password))...', array(33,'thepassword'));
```

That gives you the placeholder rather than the string literal.