# error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Tags: sql, node.js

I have a table 'article' with column 'content' .I want to query Postgresql in order to search for a string contained in variable 'temp'.This query works fine-

```
pool.query("select * from article where upper(content) like upper('%some_value%')");
```

But when I use placeholder $1 and [temp] in place of some_value , I get the above error -

```
pool.query("select * from article where upper(content) LIKE upper('%$1%')",[temp] );
```

Note - Here $1 is a placeholder and should be replaced by the value in [temp] , but it treats '%$1%' as a string , I guess. Without the quotes ' ' , the LIKE operator doesn't work. I have also tried the query -

```
pool.query("select * from article where upper(content) LIKE upper(concat('%',$1,'%'))",[temp] );
```

to ensure $1 is not treated as a string literal but it gives the error - 
    error: could not determine data type of parameter $1

Comment: what versions of node and packages do you have installed?

Comment: node 7.7.1 , other packages are also recent , as I installed them few days ago.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error message, however the following answer makes a good deal of sense in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26209691/674225. i.e: SQL uses `'` for string literals.

Comment: You mean the second query I posted works fine on your system? Also the answer link you gave simply suggests that placeholders should be used without quotes , but I don't think SQL's LIKE operator works without quotes...

Comment: The parameter notation definitely needs to be outside quotes. I hadn't tried the `concat` version, which I thought would work, but --like you know-- doesn't. Found that the `||` solved the problem and submitted an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pool.query(
  "select * from article where upper(content) LIKE upper('%' || $1 || '%')",
  [temp]
).then( res => {console.log(res)}, err => {console.error(err)})
```

This works for me. I just looked at [this Postgres doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to try and understand what `concat` was doing to the parameter notation. Can't say that I understand the difference between using `||` operators and using `concat` string function at this time.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found to do this is like the following:

```
// You can remove [0] from character[0] if you want the complete value of character.
  database.query(`
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE LOWER(users.name) LIKE LOWER($1)
    ORDER BY users.id ASC`, 
    ["%" + character[0] + "%"]
  );
```

// [`%${character}%`] string literal alternative to the last line in the function call.

---

There are several things going on here, so let me break each line it down.

1. `SELECT * FROM users`

   - This is selecting all the columns associated with table `users`
2. `WHERE LOWER(users.name) LIKE $1`

   - This is filtering out all the results from the first line so that `where` the `name`(lowercased) column of the `users` table is like the parameter `$1`.
3. `ORDER BY users.id ASC`

   - This is optional, but I like to include it because I want the data returned to me to be in ascending order (that is from 0 to infinity, or starting low and going high) based on the `users.id` or the `id` column of the `users` table. A popular alternative for client-side data presentation is `users.created_at DESC` which shows the latest user (or more than likely an article/post/comment) by its creation date in reverse order so you get the newest content at the top of the array to loop through and display on the client-side.
4. `["%" + character + "%"]`

   - This part is the second argument in the .query method call from the database object (or `client` if you kept with that name, you can name it what you want, and database to me makes for more a sensical read than "client", but that is just my personal opinion, and it's highly possible that "client" may be the more technically correct term to use). 
     The second argument needs to be an array of values. It takes the place of the parameters inserted in the query string, for example, `$1` or `?` are examples of parameter placeholders which are filled in with a value in the 2nd argument's array of values. In this case, I used JavaScript's built-in string concatenation to provide a "includes" ***`like`*** pattern, or in plain-broken English, "find me columns that contain a 'this' value" where `name`(lowercased) is the column and `character` is the parameter variable value. I am pulling in the parameter value for the `character` variable from `req.params` (the URL, so `http://localhost:3000/users/startsWith/t`), so combining that with `%` on both ends of the parameter, it returns me all the values that contain the letter t since is the first (and only) character here in the URL.

---

I know this is a VERY late response, but I wanted to respond with a more thorough answer in case anyone ***else*** needed it broken down further.

Answer (score 0):

In my case :
My variable was $1, instead of ?1 ...
I was customizing my query with @Query